# Twitter connect popup page for iphone

Tags: iphone, twitter

Does Twitter has the iPhone SDK which has a login popup like facebook iOS SDK?

Comment: I don't know about the downvote either. I don't think I asked something gibberish.

Comment: You only have 11 hous left, if you think that my answer is good, gives me bounty; otherwise, you still lose your points

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't have. What I can recommend you is to use [this DDSocialDialog library](http://github.com/digdog/DDSocialDialog) (just 4 classes) and you can have something similar

Answer (score 2):

Look for this source code:

http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Thanks to [Ben Gottlieb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6694/ben-gottlieb).

It opens the login page as a modal view.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the page in this:

https://github.com/cglong/FBDialog

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. You'll have to implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, they don't.  But, as facebook, their REST API can return JSON payload and that's very easy to retrieve using NSURLConnection and parse using the JSON-Framework that you van find [here](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework)

Answer (score 0):

`No Twitter does not have the login pop up as facebook has`. You have to create your own login page. or you can get few from the open source.

Matt Gemmell and Craig Hockenberry, developer of Twitterific created [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa), an easy-to-use library of classes providing methods that make it extremely easy for the developer to access the Twitter API. see I believe there are a few other libs out there, but it's just as easy to roll your own because like Macha says above Twitter's API gives you the option to have the feeds in XML or JSON format.

Try this link
[MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa)

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: Yeah, that library is really good but doesn't answer the question:)

Comment: The library does not answer your question. Your question is alread answered by me and is highlighted. thats `NO`